# Html is not parsing while parsing a template to send email

Tags: html, email, go

I am working on a SAAS based project for which I need to send emails to different clients on different events.

I am using email templates which use tokens (in format {{.TOKENNAME}}) that are made dynamic while sending emails. Now these token are parsed by using "html/template" package.

following is the custom function that I have made to parse these tokens into email body.

```
    type EmailTemplate struct{
    BookingDetails              string
}

type EmailRequest struct{
    EmailTo      string
    EmailBody    string
}

// get saved html with tokens from database
notificationTemplate, errVal := merchantDb.GetNotificationTemplate()
request := EmailRequest{
    "test@example.com", 
    notificationTemplate.Content,
}
templateData.BookingDetails += "<p><span>Industry</span><span>"+industry.IndustryName+"</span></p>"

request.EmailSend(templateData)


func (request *EmailRequest) EmailSend(notificationTemplateData interface{}) (bool, error) {
    body, errParse := ParseTemplate(request.EmailBody, notificationTemplateData)
    //email sending code here 
}

func ParseTemplate(templateHtml string, data interface{}) (string, error) {
    var body string
    t, err := template.New("my_template").Parse(templateHtml)
    if err != nil {
        return body, err
    }
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

    if err = t.Execute(buf, data); err != nil {
        return body, err
    }
    body = buf.String()
    return body, nil
}
```

Where templateHtml is the email body with tokens and data is the interface holding dynamic values for these tokens. When I use ParseTemplate function to parse tokens as string values then it works fine. But if I have to parse html in one of my tokens then it parses html as string and in email displays html as string.

Can anybody tell me what should I do to parse html in ParseTemplate function?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "it parses html as string".  Show examples of your input and output, and what output you expected instead.

Comment: @Flimzy, here is my input: "bookingDetails += "<p><span>Industry</span><span>"+industry.IndustryName+"</span></p>"" and output is: "&lt;p&gt;&lt;span&gt;Industry&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span&gt;Home Cleaning&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"

Comment: That should be in your question.

Comment: Okay. But did you get any solution for it ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to define `type EmailTemplate struct` as

```
type EmailTemplate struct{
    BookingDetails template.HTML
}
```

Comment: What kind of value will be assigned to BookingDetails ??

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your strings containing html to the type template.HTML:

```
str := "<br>" // gets converted and renders as "&lt;br&gt;"
strSafe := template.HTML(str) // renders as "<br>"
```

This marks your string as safe. When you do that, be sure that the containing html is safe, especially when it comes from a third party.

Comment: when I am casting it as template.HTML it is giving me this error: cannot convert data (type interface {}) to type "html/template".HTML: need type assertion. I have taken my html fragment as type interface in function

Comment: Please show us your code where you assemble the `data`.

Comment: You could call `body, errParse := ParseTemplate(request.EmailBody, template.HTML(notificationTemplateData))`. In this case you have to be absolutely certain that there is no malicious code in the body. At least that should compile.

Comment: Still getting the same error by using above statement: cannot convert notificationTemplateData (type interface {}) to type "html/template".HTML: need type assertion

Comment: I see. You could change the signature of EmailSend to `EmailSend(notificationTemplateData string)`. But this is getting a bit hacky. You can pass structs as data to the Execute func and render the fields with pipelines. But that would be quite another matter.

Comment: Sorry I did not get what you wrote

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170371/discussion-between-amandeep-kaur-and-mbuechmann).